# Creating virtualenv of backdated python on windows

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I have Python 3.7 installed in my Windows and want to make a virtual env of python 3.5. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Install Python 3.5; you cannot make a virtualenv without having the proper version of Python globally. After installing Python 3.5 run:

```
C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install virtualenv
C:\Python35\python.exe C:\Python35\Scripts\virtualenv venv35
```

Use any preferred name instead of `venv35`. The virtual environment will be created in the current directory. That is, if the current dir is `C:\Users\Archit` the virtual environment will be `C:\Users\Archit\venv35`.

Comment: When i tried making virtualenv i faced this error these both are one.    Using base prefix 'D:\\python3.5'
New python executable in D:\python3.5_venv\pyenv3.5\Scripts\python.exe
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00003ec8 (most recent call first):
ERROR: The executable D:\python3.5_venv\pyenv3.5\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is 'd:\\python3.5_venv' (should be 'd:\\python3.5_venv\\pyenv3.5')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable

Comment: Note: some Windows users have reported this error when they installed Python for "Only this user" or have multiple versions of Python installed. Copying the appropriate PythonXX.dll to the virtualenv Scripts/ directory may fix this problem.

Comment: Also, make sure you've elected to use the 'py launcher' which is an optional feature within the installer. It will make it easier to manage different versions of python on one Windows machine.